# Why my regular expression not work in view page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm beginner in `asp.net mvc`, and I want to define validation rule on the HTML TextBox. For that purpose I wrote the model and bind that model for TextBox with this Razor code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.PhoneNumbe ,new { @class="form-control", placeholder = "Phone",id="PhonNo" } )
```

And in the model I wrote this regular expression:

```
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "UPRN must be numeric")]
public string PhoneNumbe { get; set; }
```

But when I run application and enter character, I can't see any alert message! What happen? How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Also see: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718004/ASP-NET-MVC-Client-Side-Validation

Comment: and https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/validation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see message of validation when you're typing characters then you have to use client-side validation.

First check web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>  
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

For validation on the client side is also necessary that in the HTML code that will send to the browser, there were references to the three JavaScript libraries:

- /Scripts/jQuery-1.X.X.min.js
- /Scripts/jQuery.validate.min.js
- /Scripts/jQuery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

Then put into your view `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` or `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumbe)` to  validation message for only one field